# Can we trigger each notebook with a individual cluster in data bricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks

do anybody know that in data bricks can we run our notebooks in separate-separate clusters?

example notebook 1-- cluster 1
notebook2 -- cluster 2

notebook1 and notebook 2 are parallel notebooks inside master notebook ( name as notebook_main)

thanks in advance !!

Comment: how do you run them? `dbutils.notebook.run`?

Comment: import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps
var notebooks = Seq(
  NotebookData("/Users/apal40@optumcloud.com/CPM Module",0,Map("Env" -> test.toString())),
  NotebookData("/Users/msai9@optumcloud.com/engage", 0,Map("Env" -> test.toString())),
  NotebookData("/Users/msai9@optumcloud.com/HSC_Module",0,Map("Env" -> test.toString())),
  NotebookData("/Users/sbhatt62@optumcloud.com/SDMMODULE",0,Map("Env" -> test.toString()))
)
val res = parallelNotebooks(notebooks)
Await.result(res, 30 seconds) 
res.value

Comment: via above code we are calling multiple notebooks

Comment: it's not clear how `parallelNotebooks` works